# How do I hide closed boards in the Trello Android app?

Tags: trello

I see all of my closed boards and is a bit annoying not knowing what is what. Is there a way to hide them all?

Comment: You are referring to the native app?

Comment: Yes, sorry I didn't specify (or know the difference)